# SSL Client Certificate Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway

I am not sure how client side ssl certifcate works. Please clarify the behavior in following scenario.

In case of Amazon API coupled with client side AWS Generated SSL certificates ,

I wish to know whether these certificates are added by API gateway on invocation of apis or the client who is consuming these apis need to add them.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway adds the certificate to the request. Your server would then check the certificate attached to the request to verify that the request came from API Gateway.